# How to find an element by name using Nokogiri?

Tags: xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

```
<input type="Checkbox" checked="" name="new">
```

if I have the above html in a document, how would I find it by searching for its name attribute?

Edit 1: Clarified that I was looking for a solution using Nokogiri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$agent.page.at('[@name="new"]')
```

That should do the trick, where $agent is a variable containing the Mechanize agent