# Get node by attribute value

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to get a node by its attribute value. The XML was generated by someone else and looks like this:

```
<destination atlas_id = "val">
  <history>
    <history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
    </history>
  </history>
</destination>

<destination atlas_id = "val2">
  <history>
    <history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
    </history>
  </history>
</destination>

<destination atlas_id = "val3">
  <history>
    <history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
      <history>
        <![CDATA[content]]>
      </history>
    </history>
  </history>
</destination>
```

My code has the variables `dest_file` and `id` which are set earlier to reference the correct file and value respectively. I tested them in IRB and their values are correct:

```
node = dest_file.xpath("//destination[@atlas_id = #{id}]").first
doc.text node.xpath("//history/history/history").text unless node.nil?
```

I want to fetch the content/text of the third nested `<history>`, the one that contains CDATA belonging to the the `<destination>` node with the relevant `atlas_id` value.

Even when `id = val2`, I'm getting the content of `<history>` belonging to `<destination atlas_id = "val1">`. I was referencing "[How to search by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903219/nokogiri-search-by-attribute-value)" when I wrote the code to find nodes by attribute value.

Why am I getting the content for the wrong history node? After testing in IRB

```
node = dest_file.xpath("//destination[@atlas_id = #{id}]").first
```

seems to be returning the correct node but the following line gets the wrong content. The problem might be small or silly but I can't spot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second XPath expression, `//history/history/history`, since it starts with `/` it will search from *the root of the document*, and since you use `//` you will get *all* nodes that match from anywhere in the document.

What you probably want to do is select only those nodes under the context node, which is the `destination` node you have already selected. You can use `.` at the start of the expression for this:

```
.//history/history/history
```